# Простой файловый менеждер

Tags: php

Почему в ссылку не вставляется путь для папки, и как выводить изображение папки, только для папки?

Сейчас у меня выводится изображения папки для всех файлов, кроме текстовых и изображений.

Можно ли вообще, как-нибудь сделать проверку для папки?

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$img = 'papka.jpg';
$img2 = 'file.jpg';
$img3 = 'img.jpg';

$dir = 'C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\kurs\16\dzfm';
$dir2 = 'localhost\kurs\16\dzfm';

$files = scandir($dir);

echo '<ul style="padding: 0">';
foreach ($files as $f) {
    echo '<li style="list-style: none;">';

   if(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'txt'){
        echo '<img src="' . $img2 . '">';
        echo "<span style=' display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;'>$f</span>";
   }
    elseif(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpg'){
        echo '<img src="' . $img3 . '">';
        echo "<span style=' display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;'>$f</span>";
   }

   else{
        echo ""?><a href="<?php '"' . $dir2 . '\\' . $f . '"'?>"><?php echo "";

        echo '<img src="' . $img . '">';
        echo "<span style=' display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;'>$f</span>";

        echo '</a>';
   }

   echo '</li>';
}

 echo '</ul>';

 echo $dir2 . '\\' . $f;
?>

<a href=<?php '"' . $dir2 . '\\' . $f . '"'?>>ссылка<a/>
```

Я заменил else, на такую проверку и почему-то тоже всё выводит, а не только папки

```
elseif(!is_file($dir2 . '\\' . $f)){
```

так тоже не работает elseif

```
(is_dir($dir2 . '\\' . $f)){
```

Comment: Вы зачем-то выводите текст вперемешку с PHP в else - зачем? Выводите в else сразу ссылку без ""?> или <?php echo - сейчас вы из PHP файла пытаетесь вывести строки ДЛЯ PHP файла. Выводите также как и в предыдущих условиях, без этого.

Comment: вы никогда не пробовали сначала массив данных подготовить, а потом его вывести? а не все в кучу сложить?

Comment: Сначала работаете с данными без их вывода - создаёте массив. И только потом выводите их так, как надо. Не будет этой каши. Всё будет аккуратно и красиво. И не запутаетесь. Попробуйте. Обновите потом вопрос новым кодом. Никто в том, что сейчас копаться не будет.